# Using webwrite in MATLAB using JSON

Tags: json, matlab, http, post, cloud

I am writing a MATLAB simulation to upload some random data to M2X, an AT&T website.

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
M2XURL = 'https://api-m2x.att.com/v2/devices/xxxxxxxx1f248cabb6dc079exxxxxxxx/streams/TEMPARATURE';
writeApiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
data =struct('TEMPARATURE',30);
options= weboptions('MediaType','application/json','contenttype','json','RequestMethod','post','KeyName','X-M2X-KEY','KeyValue',writeApiKey);
response = webwrite(M2XURL,data,options);
```

and the response I get is The server returned the message: `Method Not Allowed` for URL,
`'https://api-m2x.att.com/v2/devices/1b1528cc1f248cabb6dc079e2decf176/streams/TEMPARATURE'` (with HTTP response code 405).

Is there any specific url to update a value to M2X?

Comment: Are you sure about the URL? Temperature is spelled wrong in your code.

Comment: I got the solution for this. Code is alright. I was using bit older version of matlab. so the PUT protocol wasn't supporting. This code will work if we are using Matlab 16b. Thanks for Checking in.